# Unable to reclaim Storage for Actions and Packages after deleting all files

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-actions-runners

When i try to run a github action (it will build android apk) it showing an error

> You've used 100% of included services for GitHub Storage (GitHub
> Actions and Packages). GitHub Actions and Packages won’t work until a
> monthly spending limit is set.

[image: Storage for Actions and Packages]
So i delete all Artifacts files but after i delete each Artifacts the Storage for Actions is not reducing 
For example i delete 20 Artifacts file and each contains 20mb. Which means 400Mb and when i check the "Storage for Actions" it is still showing it is overflowed 
Why this is happening?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what files have been removed? The stats are refreshed on a scheduled basis. After some time it should reflect the current state. You can also reduce the retention time of the artifacts to avoid exceeding the quota in the future. https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-08-github-actions-ability-to-change-retention-days-for-artifacts-and-logs/

Comment: I updated the question with details please check

Comment: Do we know what the schedule for the usage recalculation is?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an identical problem. After looking at the docs, it seems it takes one hour for storage usage to update.

From the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/viewing-your-github-actions-usage#viewing-github-actions-usage-for-your-organization):

> Storage usage data synchronizes every hour.

Comment: I have removed all the artifacts, workflow runs using github API, and waited for 6-7hours, but still, there's no change in the `Storage for Actions and Packages` section in billing page.

Comment: The email that GitHub sends out when the limit exceeded also mentions a date when usage will be reset, but it makes sense that you should be able to delete unneeded Action and Package files and reclaim space in a more timely way.